# Getting error 403 on serverside:true for datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

So i'm using codeigniter (PHP MVC Framework) and Im using this datatables configuration:

```
$("#masterlist").DataTable( {
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url" : "/student/json_students",
        "type" : "POST"
    }
});
```

if i go to domain/student/json_students normally via the browser I am able to view the json object properly.

also, if i use regular ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   "url" : "/student/json_students",
   "type" : "POST"
});
```

it works! So how come the 'serverSide' option in datatables is throwing a error 403 (forbidden)?

Comment: what did it show in your browser console under network tab?

Comment: @jagad89 status:403 type:xhr for json_students. initiator: jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4

Answer (score 0):

Use it as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#masterlist').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "<?php echo base_url();?>/student/json_students"
    } );
});
```

Refrence [DataTable Server side](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: i've already done that. putting it in ready wont change anything considering my js is at the bottom of the file and the fact im getting a 403 means the ajax executed w/o problems. im also getting the proper path since i can open it on the browser when i ask js to log the url.